# Select rows based on group_by rows and its column values

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr, grouping

I made a reproducible data set.

In this dataset I am trying to get the columns grouped by "value" and "category" and get the largest value of all in the "category" only if there is "value" that is greater than 4 in value in that group_by

The other way to put the question is to Get the largest "value" for each "category" for each label, only if there is a "value" greater than 4 in that "category"

```
das <- data.frame(val=1:24,
              weigh=c(10,10,10,11,11,11,20,20,20,21,21,21,30,30,30,31,31,31,40,40,40,41,41,41),
              value=c(4.1,3.2,4.3,1.1,2.2,5.3,2.1,2.2,3.3,3.1,8.2,1.3,3.6,2.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,1.1,7.2,4.5,5.1,3.2,2.5,9.1),
              label=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4),
              category=c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"))

val weigh value label category
1   1   10  4.1 1   A
2   2   10  3.2 1   B
3   3   10  4.3 1   C
4   4   11  1.1 1   A
5   5   11  2.2 1   B
6   6   11  5.3 1   C
7   7   20  2.1 2   A
8   8   20  2.2 2   B
9   9   20  3.3 2   C
10  10  21  3.1 2   A
11  11  21  8.2 2   B
12  12  21  1.3 2   C
13  13  30  3.6 3   A
14  14  30  2.1 3   B
15  15  30  3.1 3   C
16  16  31  3.1 3   A
17  17  31  3.1 3   B
18  18  31  1.1 3   C
19  19  40  7.2 4   A
20  20  40  4.5 4   B
21  21  40  5.1 4   C
22  22  41  3.2 4   A
23  23  41  2.5 4   B
24  24  41  9.1 4   C
```

This is expected output

```
 val weigh value label category
 1  1   10  4.1 1   A
 5  6   11  5.3 1   C
 2  2   10  3.2 1   B
 10 10  21  3.1 2   A
 3  11  21  8.2 2   B
 9  9   20  3.3 2   C
 2  19  40  7.2 4   A
 4  20  40  4.5 4   B
 6  24  41  9.1 4   C
```

I tried following, but not getting expected output. Here I am just getting only the values > 4 here, not all the largest number in that category with this label

```
das1 <- das[das$value >4,]

result <- das1 %>% 
  group_by(category,label) %>% 
  slice(which.max(value))


 val weigh value label category
 1  1   10  4.1 1   A
 5  6   11  5.3 1   C
 3  11  21  8.2 2   B
 2  19  40  7.2 4   A
 4  20  40  4.5 4   B
 6  24  41  9.1 4   C
```

Comment: Do you mean grouped by `label` and `category`?

Comment: @CalumYou Get the largest "value" for each "category" from each label, only if there is a "value" greater than 4 in that "category"

Comment: I am still confused about the expected output. For example, see the 3rd row in your expected output, with `label = 1` and `category = B`. Why is this row kept, with `value = 3.2` which is less than 4?

Comment: @CalumYou Its included because that is the largest value for that label in that category. So in first place this is did only because there is a value in the label 1 with value greater than 4. If you take the case of label =3 you will see nothing is selected as there is no values greater than 4 with the label 3.

Comment: So if there is a value greater than 4 in that label THEN need to find the largest value of all the category within that label ( this largest value might be less than 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could first `group_by` `label` and `filter` groups which has `any` `value > 4` and then select only row with `max` `value` in each `label` and `category`.

```
library(dplyr)

das %>%
   group_by(label) %>%
   filter(any(value > 4)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   group_by(label, category) %>%
   slice(which.max(value))


#    val weigh value label category
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   
#1     1    10   4.1     1 A       
#2     2    10   3.2     1 B       
#3     6    11   5.3     1 C       
#4    10    21   3.1     2 A       
#5    11    21   8.2     2 B       
#6     9    20   3.3     2 C       
#7    19    40   7.2     4 A       
#8    20    40   4.5     4 B       
#9    24    41   9.1     4 C
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your worded description is confusing, because you keep saying different things. This matches your expected output, and the interpretation is

Get the largest "value" for each "category" for each label, only if there is a "value" greater than 4 in that "**label**" (here you said category in the OP)

```r
library(tidyverse)
das <- data.frame(
  val = 1:24,
  weigh = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41),
  value = c(4.1, 3.2, 4.3, 1.1, 2.2, 5.3, 2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 3.1, 8.2, 1.3, 3.6, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 1.1, 7.2, 4.5, 5.1, 3.2, 2.5, 9.1),
  label = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  category = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C")
)

das %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  filter(any(value > 4)) %>%
  group_by(label, category) %>%
  filter(value == max(value)) %>%
  arrange(label, category)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   label, category [9]
#>     val weigh value label category
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   
#> 1     1    10   4.1     1 A       
#> 2     2    10   3.2     1 B       
#> 3     6    11   5.3     1 C       
#> 4    10    21   3.1     2 A       
#> 5    11    21   8.2     2 B       
#> 6     9    20   3.3     2 C       
#> 7    19    40   7.2     4 A       
#> 8    20    40   4.5     4 B       
#> 9    24    41   9.1     4 C
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: yea I am sorry.. Its quite confusing the way I described. But you answer is exactly what I am looking for. I am accepting the other one just coz he put it at first.